# Cascading prompt in BO Webi without using universe?

Tags: business-objects, webi

Is it possible to create a cascading prompt in Business object webi without using universe? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to change the code of viewer.js and prompts.js or developing a new interface to accept report parameters.